# how to make container view background transparent only not everything?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have container view above my view controller

and this container hold xib and have photos in this Xib

the problem is the photos is png and i want the container to be transparent to show me my view colour

[image]

[image]

```
    public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TNImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TNImageSliderCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelSliderName.text = sliderNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

this sample how i fill the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` and

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TNImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TNImageSliderCollectionViewCell
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.row]
cell.imageView.alpha = 0.5
cell.labelSliderName.text = sliderNames[indexPath.row]
return cell
```

Comment: this make photo alpha 0.5 but i want the photo alpha = 1 only I want the container background to be transparent

Comment: How it can see, because the imageView on the top layer on it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OR29E.png  this shape transparent i want to the the blue background with it

Comment: What is your view's color, White Color??

Comment: no it's blue or actual gradinet just the container view when i write clear colour give me white Color

Comment: let try tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Answer (score 2):

You should change the opacity value of the containers background color not the alpha.Alpha value is applied to all the subviews as well.